# R. Array-based replacement of string matches in data frame

Tags: arrays, r, text, data-cleaning

I have a data frame column containing sentences.
Within these sentences, there's the whole host of words which I want to remove.

These are words that could appear more than once in a single sentence, and when found I want to remove these words entirely.

e.g.
Sample list of words for removal: ("the", "and", "a") * (list will have 100's of words)

String Before: "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and cat"
String After: "quick brown fox jumps over lazy dog cat"

```
 sentences <- as.data.frame(c("it's a new sentence","another sentence i've constructed","and a third sentence"))
 colnames(sentences) <- c("sentence")

stop_words <- list( "i" = '', "a" = "", "me" = '' , "my" = "", "myself" = "", "we" = "", "it's" = "", "a" = "", "i've" = "")

 stop_pattern <- paste0("\\b", "(", paste0(stop_words, collapse = "|"),")","\\b")
 trimws(gsub("\\s{2}", " ", gsub(stop_pattern, "", sentences$sentence)))
```

Output should remove words such as "I've" from the above sentences, however fails to do so.

Output is as shows:
[1] "it's a new sentence"               "another sentence i've constructed" "and a third sentence"

Comment: The `removeWords()`-function from the `tm`-package is build for this purpose. Perhaps this will help you.

Comment: Try: `no_stropwords <- gsub(paste0(stop_words, collapse = "|"), "", sentences)` then `trimws(gsub("\\s{2}", "\\s", no_stropwords ))`. The stop list should be `list( 'i', 'me', etc..`

Comment: @PabloRod I think the problem with that approach is that it will not only remove the specific words, but also these strings if they are part of another word, for example with the `stop_list` from OP every `'i'` in every word will be removed.

Comment: Then `stop_pattern <- paste0("\\b", "(", paste0(stop_words, collapse = "|"),")","\\b")

trimws(gsub("\\s{2}", " ", gsub(stop_pattern, "", sentences)))`

Comment: Hello - your solution doesn't seem to work for my updated problem. Are you able to review once again with the code I have included and test if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
stop_pattern <- paste0("\\b", "(", paste0(stop_words, collapse = "|"),")","\\b") trimws(gsub("\\s{2}", " ", gsub(stop_pattern, "", sentences)))
```

Comment: I've managed to import the following into my project. It doesn't seem to work. I have a feeling that it might not handle this situation well when I'm pointing towards a data frame column.

 stop_pattern <- paste0("\\b", "(", paste0(stop_words, collapse = "|"),")","\\b")
 trimws(gsub("\\s{2}", " ", gsub(stop_pattern, "", sentences$sentence)))

Comment: I've updated my question above to make it a bit more clear with exactly what I'm doing. For some reason I can't get your code to work, although it does look promising!